How can I send messages to the unbanned user and what did I dо wrong?
I have the unban function in my disnake bot. After I unban, the bot should send a personal message to the user, but I got an error there.
Code:
@bot.slash_command(name="unban",
                  description="Разбан пользователя (указание причины обязательно)"
                  )
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(inter, member_id: str, reason: str):
    user = await bot.get_or_fetch_user(int(member_id))
    await inter.response.send_message(f'{user.mention} разбанен по причине: "{reason}".')
    await bot.guilds[0].unban(user, reason = reason)
    ban_list_channel = bot.get_channel(1274693427811844157)
    notification_channel = bot.get_channel(1274130140489580584)

    unban_embed = disnake.Embed(title = 'Пользователь разбанен!',
                              description = f'{user.mention} разбанен на сервере.\n{ban_list_channel.mention} обновлен.',
                              color = disnake.Colour.yellow(),
                              timestamp= datetime.now()
                              )

    unban_embed_for_user = disnake.Embed(title = 'Вы были разбанены!',
                              description = f'{user.mention} разбанен на сервере {bot.guilds[0].name}.\nПричина: "{reason}"\nПриглашаем вас: https://discord.gg/hwQM6GG4kB',
                              color = disnake.Colour.green(),
                              timestamp= datetime.now()
                              )

    lines = []

    with open('source/txt/ban_list.txt', 'r') as ban_list:
            line = ban_list.readline()
            if str(member_id) not in line:
                lines.append(line)
            while line:
                line = ban_list.readline()
                if str(member_id) not in line:
                    lines.append(line)

    with open('source/txt/ban_list.txt', 'r+') as ban_list:
        ban_list.truncate()
        for line in lines:
            ban_list.write(line)
        text = ban_list.read()

    await notification_channel.send(embed = unban_embed)
    await ban_list_channel.purge(limit=3)

    ban_list_embed = disnake.Embed(title = 'Список забаненных пользователей:',
                              description = text,
                              color = disnake.Colour.red(),
                              timestamp= datetime.now()
                              )

    await ban_list_channel.send(embed = ban_list_embed)

    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await inter.delete_original_message()
    await user.send(embed = unban_embed_for_user)

This is the error:
Ignoring exception in slash command 'unban':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 1083, in call_param_func
    return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\utils.py", line 567, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\ds_bot\trader.py", line 172, in unban
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\abc.py", line 1748, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\http.py", line 409, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
disnake.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1378, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\Icold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 737, in invoke
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

I tried to add a sleep function because I thought that the response from the server wasn't delivered yet, but this thought is wrong.

The bot cannot send a message to someone who was banned and now unbanned since the user is not sharing a guild with the bot therefore your bot wont be able to send a message. If the user would be in the same guild as the bot it will work thats why when banning someone you are able to send a message to the user before removing them from the guild.

I have three opinion,
User's Privacy Settings: The user might have their privacy settings configured to disallow DMs from server members who are not friends. Or maybe The user might have blocked the bot, preventing it from sending DMs. maybe The user might have disabled receiving DMs from members of the server.
Have you update the disnake? It can be a library issue.

I have downloaded disnake recently. There is no problem with privacy, because after ban bot send message correctly.
